# Conversion of xlabels to strings in dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

So, the code ive written is working but the final output graph isnt plotted the way i needed it to be, i tried converting the index to strings but that isnt working(the index Item are 4 digit codes)i want the entire item code in the xlabel.
Eg 1250 instead of it being ranged as it currently is.

Output graph  :  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5KHl.png)

how do i go about fixing this.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

#File path has to be changed as seen fit
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Karthik\Desktop\personal\python\data.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df.set_index("Item ", inplace=True)
df.index = df.index.map(str)
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Avail mapping'),
    dcc.Graph(id='example',
        figure=
        { 'data':
         [{'x': df.index, 'y': df['Availability'], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'avail'},
            ], 

            'layout': {
                'title': 'Basic Dash Example'
            }
           } 
        )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest importing the index column in pandas as strings, e.g.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('csv.csv', index_col='Item', dtype={'Item': str}, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

In this way, the index will be imported with uninterpreted string values.